# PostgreSQL insert all rows from one table to another with identical column names and types but different positions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

My use-case in Postgres 9.6 is the need to copy all rows from a number of wide (lots of columns) tables to "identical" different tables.  The different tables have the same columns with same types, indexes, etc, but the positions of the columns are different, causing both below attempts to fail.  Is there a way for it to match up columns by name instead of position, WITHOUT writing all columns out in the statement?

```
INSERT INTO table_b select * FROM table_a
```

Fails with `ERROR:  column "request_base" is of type boolean but expression is of type text`

```
INSERT INTO table_b
   select (data::table_b).*
     FROM (select * from table_a) as data;
```

Fails with `ERROR:  cannot cast type record to table_b. DETAIL:  Cannot cast type uuid to boolean in column 27.`

Comment: Does `table_b` and company already have data/rows in them?

Comment: Two cheats 1) Use `pg_dump -d the_db -t the_table -a --column-inserts > somefile`. This will dump the table data as `INSERT`s with column names. You could grab the first one and modify for `SELECT` portion of statement. Though if there is a lot  of data it would be wasteful. 2) Use `select string_agg(attname, ',') from pg_attribute where attrelid = <table_name>::regclass and attnum >=1;` to build a `SELECT` column string.